# Java Socket disconnecting

Tags: java, sockets

I have a chat server running that tells me when a client connects. I want to stay connected to this server but I'm getting disconnected instantly.
Program shuts down and server says "CLIENT DISCONNECTED BRUTALLY".
How do I stay connected to the server?

```
Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))
```

Edit:
I set the timeout to 0 `socket.setSoTimeout(0);` and keepAlive to true `socket.setKeepAlive(Boolean.TRUE);` but I'm still getting disconnected instantly.

Comment: Can you post complete program?

Comment: It's not much more than that as of yet, just trying to connect as first order of business

Comment: What happens on the client side? Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: I did not write the code for the server so I'm only seeing that I'm connecting and disconnecting.

Comment: @user10990200 Is your main thread running? Looks like your thread is finished just after connecting to server.